# "MySQL support not included in PHP error" in CiviCRM-4.7.10-wordpress

Tags: mysql, php

I'm getting the error "MySQL support not included in PHP" in the CiviCRM installer wordpress page.

My setup is:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Wordpress 4.6.1
- CiviCRM 4.7.10
- php 7.0 with mysqli php extension installed

I checked that mysqli is indeed loaded by running

```
php -r 'echo extension_loaded("mysqli") ? "loaded\n" : "missing\n";'
```

Any ideas about what could be wrong? What else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7.0 isn't supported in CiviCRM 4.7.10.  Please try upgrading to 4.7.12.